# How to find if a function with multiple variables has a limit

Tags: limits, functions

As the title says - I need to find a limit (if it exists) in (0, 0) for this function:

$$f(x, y) = (x^2 + y^2)\arctan(1/(x^2+y^2)),$$ where $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

I've just started this chapter - functions with multiple variables - so I don't really know how to resolve this exercise.

Can anybody help me with this one and also explain their logic? This is something new for me and I'd like to learn it :)

Thanks.

Comment: $x^{2}+y^{2} \to 0$ and $\arctan (\frac 1 {x^{2}+y^{2}}) \to \frac {\pi} 2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is that all I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with this type of multivariable limits, one good thing to do is to go in polar coordinates.

Briefly, if you look at the $(xy)$ plane, any point $(x,y)$ can be written like $\left ( r\cos \left( \alpha \right) , r\sin \left( \alpha \right)  \right )$, where $r$ and $\alpha$ are functions of $x$ and $y$.

Now you see that $r \xrightarrow[]{(x,y) \to (0,0)} 0$, but $\alpha$ is still free to vary whatever the way it wants, so that $(x,y)$ can approach $(0,0)$ following any path imaginable (and therefore all paths).

The interest here is that $x^2+y^2 = r^2$, and this particular case enable us to deal with a single variable limit !

In our case : $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \, (x^2 + y^2) \, \arctan \left ( \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \right ) = \lim_{r \to 0} \, r^2 \, \arctan \left ( \frac{1}{r^2} \right ) = 0$$

I hope this will help